# Navigation menu in Unsemantic

Tags: html, css, wordpress, 960.gs, unsemantic-css

I need to know how to create a navigation bar with Unsemantic framework (or 960gs).

My menu structure is

`<div>
 <ul>
  <li></li>
 </ul>
</div>`.

I have tried so much, but still can't find out the problem.

EDIT

I use wordpress.So it creates navigation menu. the eventual code rendered in the browser is as follows:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="clearfix black grid-100 grid-parent mobile-grid-100 mar-top10 mar-bottom10" id="wp_nav_menu_wrapper"> 
<div class="grid-container">
 <div class="menu">
  <ul>
   <li class="page_item page-item-2">
     <a href="http://localhost/wpmarket/?page_id=2">ُSample Page</a>
   </li>
   <li class="page_item page-item-5"><a href="http://localhost/wpmarket/?page_id=5">ُSample Page 2</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

While my Wordpress markup is as follows:

```
<div class='grid-100 height-auto black-gray-bg font-tahoma'>

<nav role='navigation' class='clearfix black grid-100 grid-parent mobile-grid-100 mar-top10 mar-bottom10' id='wp_nav_menu_wrapper'> 
    <div class='grid-container'>
    <?php 

        wp_nav_menu(); 
    ?> 
</div>
</nav>

</div>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity? Why did you choose Unsemantic Framework? It doesn't look like a menu structure is a part of their framework? I would suggest using http://getbootstrap.com/ or http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

Comment: I have tried Twitter Bootstrao. Regardign responsive design and markup structure, Unsemantic is superb. It does exactly what I need. Specially it default placement is centering of elements than floating left (that Bootstrap does).

Answer (score 1):

The grid-container class is for the outer container and the grid-parent class for inner or nested containers. In your code you have this backwards.

The grid-parent class lets you align self-contained grids with normal grid items. The container holds all of the grid items. So the grid-parent is just an indicator that the  or whatever will contain further items related to its scale and ordering on the page.

You can use this structure, or similar:

```
<nav class="grid-container">
 <ul class="grid-100 grid-parent">
  <li class="grid-25">...</li>
  <li class="grid-25">...</li>
  <li class="grid-25">...</li>
  <li class="grid-25">...</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, but I doubt anyone's coming back.